# After create the build in Angular 8.... I want to change the baseURL and endpoints of the API in the code.. Is this possible

Tags: angular-directive, angular8, angular-builder

After create the build for production in Angular 8.... I want to change the baseURL and endpoints of the API in the code and don't want to rebuild the app again the changes show in the code.. Is this possible... If yes how we can do that ?

Comment: Is that configuration written in typescript file? Then not possible

Comment: Hi PSabuwala, Initially configuration written in "angular.json" after create the build with CLI ng build -- prod then everything compressed in dist folder ... In the dist folder everything are converted to js files.